# PostgreSQL function's input/output as JavaScript nested objects

Tags: postgresql, json, composite-types, string-representation

I am looking for a simple/clean way that can be used consistently to automatically input JavaScript nested objects to user-defined PostgreSQL functions and also automatically output to JavaScript nested objects.

Shall I used nested composite types? JSON? other ways?
How to parse to/from these types and JavaScript nested objects automatically?
Any better thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: A "JavaScript object" **is** JSON (=JavaScript Object Notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript nested objects can be easily (and I'd say "naturally") represented using JSON. This is "by definition" of what [JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is.

So, in your use-case **use JSON**

On the JavaScript side:

- To parse the returned values from PostgreSQL (as strings), use [`JSON.parse()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp).
- To convert JSON to a string that can be included in a SQL statement, use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp).
- You can also use some libraries, such as [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), although I've never used it myself.
- See also [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object).

---

In PostgreSQL, on top of using [`json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) data type, you might also use `jsonb`.

It's got a number of advantages (smaller size, indexability, more functions), and a few differences with `json` (order of fields is not preserved, you can't have `{"a":1,"a":2}`, and a few other smallish differences that normally don't matter).
See [Explanation of JSONB introduced by PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654170/explanation-of-jsonb-introduced-by-postgresql). Look also at the *second* answer.

---

JSON is not only available in PostgreSQL. Most current databases ([MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html), [MS SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server), [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246), [SQLite with the JSON1 extension](https://sqlite.org/json1.html), among others) also support it.

Comment: Inputs from JavaScript are best passed to PLPGSQL functions via a single jsonb argument, within the functions query results can be stored in jsonb variables using jsonb_agg and jsonb_build_object functions, outputs can be passed as a single jsonb also using jsonb_build_object where libraries such as Node pg library would interpret as native JavaScript object. This is fantastic thank you.